# Adding a button along with text to a section footer in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to add a clickable button along with some text to a section footer in a UITableView. I want to achieve the exact same result as the iOS Settings app (like the "Learn More..." button in the screenshot).

Does anyone know how Apple are doing it?

[image]

EDIT

Sorry, the screenshot I have added may be a bit misleading as I was holding down the button while taking it to make it stand out more. This is how the footer actually looks like:

[image]

I have tried implementing titleForFooterInSection and then adding a gesture recognizer to the standard footer label in willDisplayFooterView but on initial call the label is nil. I'm not sure whether this is a good approach anyway..

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return NSLocalizedString("This is some random text.", comment: "") + NSLocalizedString("Refresh", comment: "")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    guard let label = view.subviews[1].subviews.first as? UILabel else {
        return
    }
    let text = label.text!
    let underlineAttriString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: NSLocalizedString("Refresh", comment: ""))
    underlineAttriString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: range)
    label.attributedText = underlineAttriString
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(refreshTapped)))
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at UITableViewDelegate.tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
 viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? You really need to add some code to show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Spads I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Jsut use  `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection  section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150));

            header.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: tableView.frame.width-20, height: 100))
        label.text = "I tried using your code, but the footer doesn't look like the one from my screenshot. Here's what I got: Screenshot I usually work with storyboards and xibs so I don't really know how to align the text and button"
        label.numberOfLines = 4
        header.addSubview(label)

        let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: ((tableView.frame.width-100) / 2), y: 90, width: 100, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("LoadMore...", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        header.addSubview(button)

        return header

    }
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but the footer doesn't look like the one from my screenshot. Here's what I got: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/a3hmgT9) I usually work with storyboards and xibs so I don't really know how to align the text and button programmatically.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish thanks for the update but this still isn't what I'm looking for. I have updated my question with a new screenshot.